# Design pattern in iOS as decorator pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, decorator

I have a question about design patterns in iOS.

I have a UIView with a xib file. We can consider this view as a view-template.

Now we can consider several views (subclass, for example) that specify the behavior of the view template (different methods, animation, etc.).

Is there something that may be fine in my case? Some design pattern? For example, the Decorator design pattern?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? What are you looking to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Decorator Design Pattern

The Decorator design pattern attaches additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality. As does subclassing, adaptation of the Decorator pattern allows you to incorporate new behavior without modifying existing code. Decorators wrap an object of the class whose behavior they extend. They implement the same interface as the object they wrap and add their own behavior either before or after delegating a task to the wrapped object. The Decorator pattern expresses the design principle that classes should be open to extension but closed to modification.

> There are several patterns related to polymorphism that can be used within Swift, but two key ones you’ll see often are the Decorator and Adapter patterns. These are implemented using the language keywords extension and protocol respectively.
>
> The primary example of the Decorator pattern in Swift is when you create an extension. In Objective-C, there is a similar mechanism with class categories.

[iOS Design Pattern](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

http://zubairraihan.blogspot.in/2013/02/decorator-design-pattern-in-objective-c.html

http://techrantnz.blogspot.in/2011/08/decorator-builder-design-pattern-in.html

[intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81953/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-2)

Comment: Wat?  Categories and delegation have nothing to do with the decorator pattern.

Comment: Where i have written this?

Comment: `In Objective-C there are two very common implementations of this pattern: Category and Delegation`

Comment: how this statement stated that " Categories and delegation have nothing to do with the decorator pattern". even with these two decoration pattern is accomplished. please modify the current answer if you have something to add with it.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand: When one wants to implement the decorator pattern, they don't use categories or delegation.  One of which is a language feature, the other is a separate pattern unto itself.  You misunderstand what the decorator pattern entails, and copied and pasted from a Ray Wenderlich post.  I implore you to [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) about the pattern before spreading misinformation.

Comment: Take a look at proxying and message forwarding.  That's the real way to do this in Objective-C

Comment: @CodaFi so do you wish to say that the article at ray wenderlich is not correct when it comes to Decorator pattern...? Because delegation and categories are explained as part of decorator pattern..?

Comment: Category is a classical example of using the Decorator pattern on iOS. As per the definition, you add behavior to existing classes.

Comment: @CodaFi strictly speaking you are correct, however Apple states that delegation and categories are a way to fulfill the intent of the Decorator pattern without strictly adhering to the definitions.

"As with delegation, categories are not a strict adaptation of the Decorator pattern, fulfilling the intent but taking a different path to implementing that intent..."  [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

Decorator Pattern is good for this.
You can Decorate a UIView to have a scroll indicator and decorate this to a text view and so on...
Extend the view by subclassing.

In your case, You can mark the Custom Class type of the View (attribute inspector) in you XIB to point to the subclass which has this behavior.